# Javascript: Change select background-color if option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm searching a while for a Javascript function that changes the background-color of my select field if an option is selected.

HTML:

```
<select name="classNumber" id="classNumber">
 <option selected disabled value="0">Bitte Klasse auswählen</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 <option value="6">6</option>
 <option value="7">7</option>
 <option value="8">8</option>
 <option value="9">9</option>
 <option value="10">10</option>
 <option value="11">11</option>
 <option value="12">12</option>
 <option value="13">13</option>
</select>
<select name="classSpecify" id="classSpecify">
 <option selected disabled value="0">Bitte Klasse spezifizieren</option>
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="D">C</option>
 <option value="D">D</option>
 <option value="N">N (Naturwissenschaftliches Profil)</option>
 <option value="S">S (Sprachliches Profil)</option>
 <option value="G">G (Gesellschaftliches Profil)</option>
</select>
```

Javascript that is not working, at this time just for testing I set up just one select:

```
var classNumber = document.getElementById('classNumber');
var first = classNumber.options[classNumber.selectedIndex].value;
if (first != 0) {
    alert('Test');
    document.getElementById('classNumber').style.background="$green";
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to stay away from jQuery.

You are missing a few things. First off there is nothing that calling your if statement when a user ***CHANGES*** the select. Add an event .onchange to classNumber as well as background to backgroundcolor.

Like so.

```
var classNumber = document.getElementById('classNumber');
classNumber.onchange = runBackgroundChange;

function runBackgroundChange(first){
    var value = first.srcElement.options[first.srcElement.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value != 0) {
        alert('Test');
        document.getElementById('classNumber').style.backgroundColor="green";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('classNumber').style.backgroundColor="initial";
    };
}
```

Comment: Nice it Works nicely! Thanks.
@13ruce1337 I think with an else you can prevent it

Comment: @runepiper this edit here is when i realized the value being passed to the function was an Event object. When a value that is 0 is sent to this function it will go back to initial (white) backgroundcolor

Answer (score 1):

change this:

`if (first != 0) {`

to:

`if (first !== 0) {`

and this:

`"$green"`

to:

`"green"`

you want the [comparison(==](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)) operator.